# I own Minecraft but it still wants me to buy Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently got a new computer for Christmas and I already transferred the game and everything to my new PC and I can play Minecraft Java edition although it still wants me to buy Minecraft when I got to minecraft.net. I'm trying to change my name but it says I need to buy Minecraft to change my name, what do I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have logged in on minecraft.net?

Comment: Note the website is notorious for not remembering logins and serving it in the wrong language.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to check:

- Double-check you are logging in to the same Microsoft account you used to migrate your Mojang account.
- Make sure you are not logging in with your Mojang account. Migrated accounts will only be able to log in with your Microsoft account.
- If you forgot which email you used to create your Microsoft account for migration you will need to speak with Microsoft support to recover the email address used to sign-up.
- You may not have completed your migration, please go to your Mojang account profile page and start the migration again.

Source: [Microsoft Account Issues and FAQ](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4403178607373)